# Unable to import cloned projects into eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I used git to download the default calculator from [android.git.kernel](http://android.git.kernel.org/). (platform/packages/apps/Calculator.git).It succesfully cloned it but when i try to import the cloned projects into eclipse it says no projects found to import.
(file-import-existing projects into workspace-calculator).

What am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android source code for an app does not necessarily equate to Eclipse projects. You'll need to create the Eclipse projects. Create a new Android project, but in the wizard select *Create project from existing source* and select the folder where you cloned it to.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But now i have another problem.When i create the project errors are present in the calculator app which i dont think is supposed to be there.(like certain words are not being recognized etc).What is the issue.

Comment: You want to look at the errors and learn to deduce the actual problem yourself, but in the case of the Calculator project, you probably need to go to the project properties, Java Build Path, Libraries, Add JARs, then select the arity-2.1.2.jar from the project folder.

Comment: Great.It worked.Can you please tell me what the problem was and how you were able to diagnose it.

Comment: i ended up with another problem now.When i try to run the application it says execute adb unistall fron the shell.When i did that it said failure.So i tried to get into the shell and remove the default calculator application and then i tried to run it .It still does not work.What am i doing wrong.

Comment: The problem was that certain classes were defined in the jar file (which is a library of compiled code) and not in the actual source code. You can pretty much see this is the problem by mousing over the lines of code with errors and it'll say something like "class not defined" (I don't remember the actual error).

Comment: As far as your new problem goes, the calculator is a system application which most likely can't be removed. It'll be easiest to rename the app and preferably the namespace before trying to run it.